# std::bind is on stack?

Tags: c++, stdbind

I want to pass **c++ objcet member callback func** to an **"c" lib**, which just have void*. Then I use std::function to register the callback handler. But there is a problem when I cast std::function<>* to void*, seems the std::function<>* is destroyed when cast to void*.

Below is the test code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class TfLight {
 public:
  void print(int a) {
    std::cout << "TfLight::print " << a << std::endl;
  }
};

class Server {
 public:
  void run(int a) {
    std::function<void(int)>* func = reinterpret_cast<std::function<void(int)>*>(ptr);
    std::cout << func << std::endl;
    (*func)(a);
  }
  
  void register(std::function<void(int)> tf) {
    std::cout << (&tf) << std::endl;
    // f = tf;
    setPtr(&tf);
  }
  
  void setPtr(void* p) {
    ptr = p;
  }
  
  std::function<void(int)> f;
  void* ptr;
};

int main()
{
    TfLight* tf = new TfLight();
    Server* server = new Server();
    server->register(std::bind(&TfLight::print, tf, std::placeholders::_1));
    server->run(3333);
    
    delete server;
    delete tf;
}
```

When I use a global variable to holder "std::function<void(int)>", it can be called normally. How can I deal with this problem?

> But there is a problem when I cast std::function<>* to void*, seems the std::function<>* is destroyed when cast to void*

Comment: Aside: you don't need `new` to create a `TfLight` or a `Server`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::bind` is a function. It's not on the stack or the heap.

Its return value is a temporary object, and has the usual lifetime of temporaries. That's not the problem here; the `bind` return value is stored in the `std::function` passed to `register`.

In `register`, again the normal C++ rules are followed. `std::function<void(int)> tf)` is a function argument, so `&tf` remains valid for the duration of the call. As soon as `register` returns, `tf` ceases to exist. The commented-out code is correct; you should have copied it to `Server::f`.

Since you have `Server::f`, the `void* Server::ptr` seems entirely pointless. Yes, you can set `ptr` to `&f`, but why?

Comment: thx for you reply! As I said before, I need to use a c lib. I wappered it by class Server change c to c++ class.And also I need to pass the handler to c lib callback func, which just have void*, so I want to try this.

Comment: Then std::function is like other temporary object, I need to hold it. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: @dahohu527: It's quite likely that the easiest solution is to pass the entire `Server*`  as the `void*` to your C callback. After the cast back, inside the callback, you have access to all `Server` members including any stored `std::function`.